# How to use Web.Scotty stream with ResourceT?

Tags: haskell, conduit, scotty, amazonka

Having touched Haskell since 2013, I am writing a small Web.Scotty service to manage S3 bucket (with Amazonka-2.0).

The Web.Scotty part and Amazonka was pretty clear, but I am not sure how to make it work together:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    env <- Amazonka.newEnv Amazonka.discover
    scotty 3000 (app env)

app :: Amazonka.Env -> ScottyM ()
app env = do
    get "/stream-file" $ do
        runResourceT $ do
            resp <- runResourceT $ Amazonka.send env (newGetObject "bucket" "file")

            (resp ^. getObjectResponse_body) `sinkBody` (CC.map fromByteString .| CC.mapM_ (liftIO . print))

            lift $ stream $ \send flush -> do
                (resp ^. getObjectResponse_body) `sinkBody` (CC.map fromByteString .| CC.mapM_ (liftIO . send) >> liftIO flush)
```

I tried removing `runResourceT` in here, without any change:

```
resp <- Amazonka.send env (newGetObject "bucket" "file")
```

This works and prints to console successfully:

```
(resp ^. getObjectResponse_body) `sinkBody` (CC.map fromByteString .| CC.mapM_ (liftIO . print))
```

This doesn't work (if print section is commented out) with an error:

```
lift $ stream $ \send flush -> do
    (resp ^. getObjectResponse_body) `sinkBody` (CC.map fromByteString .| CC.mapM_ (liftIO . send) >> liftIO flush)
```

Error:

```
HttpExceptionRequest Request {
  host                 = "bucket.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
  port                 = 443
  secure               = True
  requestHeaders       = [("X-Amz-Content-SHA256",""),("X-Amz-Date",""),("Host","bucket.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"),("Authorization","<REDACTED>")]
  path                 = "/file"
  queryString          = ""
  method               = "GET"
  proxy                = Nothing
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 0
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutMicro 70000000
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
  proxySecureMode      = ProxySecureWithConnect
}
 ConnectionClosed
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the libraries but aren't you closing the connection by wrapping `Amazonka.send` in a `runResourceT` ?

Comment: My expectation would be that the `runResourceT` should wrap the entire monadic operation that works with the response i.e. the entire `do` block - which is even already the case with your code. Can you try getting rid of the inner `runResourceT`?

Comment: @fghibellini That's an interesting suggestion, and I tried it - still the same issue. I was trying debug with ghci-dap and something unexpected happening when it enters `stream`.

Comment: @fghibellini also, if it were the case, then the conduit with print wouldn't work either.

Comment: maybe `stream` is only "configuring" how the body is sent and not actually performing the IO. so the IO will still get executed outside of the `runResourceT`.

`print` might succeed cause it's just fast. some operations like closing connections don't always wait for completion - you can try adding a sleep in the print case to test it.

Comment: here https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.20.1/docs/src/Web.Scotty.Trans.html#line-116 you can see that as the Scotty app is compiled to a Wai app it uses the `callback` as the very last step - I imagine the callback is just the Wai "sending" function. I can't dig more. gl

Comment: Which version of Scotty are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you try:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Data.Binary.Builder (fromByteString)
import Web.Scotty
import Web.Scotty
import Data.Conduit ((.|), ConduitT, yield, runConduit)
import qualified Data.Conduit.Combinators as CC
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)

import Data.IORef

slowSource :: MonadIO m => IORef Bool -> ConduitT a ByteString m ()
slowSource state = do
  x <- liftIO $ readIORef state
  yield ("state: " <> (if x then "T" else "F") <> "\n")
  liftIO $ threadDelay 1000000
  slowSource state

main :: IO ()
main = do
    state <- newIORef False
    scotty 3000 (app state)

app :: IORef Bool -> ScottyM ()
app state = do
    get "/stream-file" $ do
      liftIO $ writeIORef state True

      stream $ \send flush -> do
          runConduit $ slowSource state .| CC.map fromByteString .| CC.mapM_ (\chunk -> liftIO (send chunk >> flush))

      liftIO $ writeIORef state False
```

you'll see:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/stream-file
state: F
state: F
state: F
state: F
state: F
^C
```

which shows that `stream` indeed only "sets up" the pipeline, but it's actually executed **after** the handler completes i.e. after your resources are deallocated (in your case the connection to AWS).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Amazonka requires that the `ResourceT` in which the `Amazonka.send` action is executed remain open until the body conduit is actually streamed.  This is kind-of, sort-of, half-documented in the [`Amazonka.Response` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/amazonka-core-2.0/docs/Amazonka-Response.html).

In your code, the `stream` call sets the streaming action, but doesn't actually execute `sinkBody`, so the outer `ResourceT` wraps up and allows the connection to be closed before Scotty invokes the streaming action including execution of the `sinkBody`.

It seems both safest and easiest to run a single `ResourceT` in your Scotty server that's opened when the server starts and only closed when the server is terminated.  (I was worried that this might leak connections, but Amazonka appears to engage in enough connection management that this isn't an issue.)

To do this without giving the Scotty package major brain surgery, you can define the following function that allows you to "unlift" the `ResourceT` transformer -- basically, to do everything in `IO` with an "escape hatch" to a single shared `ResourceT`:

```
runWithResourceT :: ((forall m a. (MonadIO m) => ResourceT IO a -> m a) -> IO b) -> IO b
runWithResourceT act = runResourceT $ withRunInIO $ \runInIO -> act (liftIO . runInIO)
```

Armed with this function, you can run your application in a single active `ResourceT` context like so:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  ...
  runWithResourceT $ \withResourceT -> scotty 3000 (app env withResourceT)
```

where the `app` runs in a normal IO-based `ScottyM` monad, using `withResourceT` where needed.  I've avoided `sinkBody` here because it invokes its own fresh `runResourceT` via `runConduitRes`.  Instead, I run the body conduit manually using `withResourceT`:

```
app :: Amazonka.Env -> (forall m a. (MonadIO m) => ResourceT IO a -> m a) -> ScottyM ()
app env withResourceT = get "/stream-file" $ do
  resp <- withResourceT $ Amazonka.send env (newGetObject "bucket" "file")
  stream $ \send flush -> do
    withResourceT $ runConduit $
      (resp ^. getObjectResponse_body._ResponseBody)
      .| mapC fromByteString
      .| mapM_C (liftIO . send)
    flush
```

Here's my full program.  I tested it, it seems to work.  Connection are sometimes held open for a bit (say, 30 seconds or so), but they're eventually closed, so it doesn't seem to be leaking anything.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Amazonka
import Amazonka.S3
import Amazonka.S3.Lens
import Conduit
import Control.Lens
import Data.Binary.Builder
import System.IO
import Web.Scotty

runWithResourceT :: ((forall m a. (MonadIO m) => ResourceT IO a -> m a) -> IO b) -> IO b
runWithResourceT act = runResourceT $ withRunInIO $ \runInIO -> act (liftIO . runInIO)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  logger <- newLogger Debug stdout
  discover <- newEnv Amazonka.discover
  let env = discover
        { Amazonka.logger = logger
        , Amazonka.region = Amazonka.Ohio
        }
  runWithResourceT $ \withResourceT -> scotty 3000 (app env withResourceT)

app :: Amazonka.Env -> (forall m a. (MonadIO m) => ResourceT IO a -> m a) -> ScottyM ()
app env withResourceT = get "/stream-file" $ do
  resp <- withResourceT $ Amazonka.send env (newGetObject "bucket" "file")
  stream $ \send flush -> do
    withResourceT $ runConduit $
      (resp ^. getObjectResponse_body._ResponseBody)
      .| mapC fromByteString
      .| mapM_C (liftIO . send)
    flush
```